# Output command result to file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Windows cmd file has the following line

```
  wget "http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.5.3.tar.gz" -P C:\temp >> dld.log
```

After executing the dld.log file is empty.
What is wrong with output redirection?
It is necessary that the output of wget execution is written to the dld.log file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wget` redirects output to `stderr` mostly to split off from the results data.

So direct answer to to make the current redirect code work is to use `2>&1` to direct `sterr` stream to `stdout` as in:

```
(wget "http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.5.3.tar.gz" -P "C:\temp")>>dld.log 2>&1
```

However, `wget` has log functions built in which makes more sense. The switch is `--output-file`

```
wget "http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.5.3.tar.gz" -P "C:\temp" --output-file=dld.log
```

See the [`wget` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Logging-and-Input-File-Options.html) for more info.